# What is equation of straight line for a ideal blackbody on the color color diagram?

Tags: star, observational-astronomy, astrophysics, data-analysis, photometry

The color-color diagram is a plot between $U-B$ vs $B-V$ values.

For a ideal blackbody, **what is the equation of this line?**

In other words, **what does the linear relation between $U-B$ and $B-V$ look like?**

Comment: I saw this in a book (carol ostlie) where a st line was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Planck's law: $$F(\lambda,T) = c  \lambda^{-5}  (e^{d/(\lambda  T)} - 1)^{-1}$$.

Since magnitude is defined as, $M = -2.5 \log_{10}(F) + \textrm{constant}$, the color index $A-B$ is
$$(A - B) = -2.5 \log_{10}(F(\lambda_A,T)/F(\lambda_B,T))$$.

To answer your question, use an appropriate effective wavelength of $U,B,V$. Link $U-B$ and $B-V$ via temperature, you should get $U-B = f(B-V)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this site has MathJaX enabled, so you can format formulas using $\TeX$

Comment: This is only approximately correct. The flux densities have to be integrated over the appropriate filter response functions first.

Comment: So will it be a straight line?

Comment: It depends on temperature evolution because $U-B = f(T)$ and $B-V = g(T)$.